# Stop time.NewTimer initialized inside for loop

Tags: loops, go, timer, deferred-execution

I have a program similar to below program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go endProgram(ch)
    printFunc(ch)
}

func printFunc(ch chan string) {
    for {
        timeout := time.NewTimer(getTimeoutDuration())
        defer timeout.Stop()
        select {
        case s := <-ch:
            fmt.Println(s)
            return
        case <-timeout.C:
            fmt.Println("Current value")
        }
    }
}

func endProgram(ch chan string) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 8)
    ch <- "Exit function"
}

func getTimeoutDuration() time.Duration {
    return time.Second * 3
}
```

What is the best way to stop the `timeout` timer in this case?

I know that above is not the recommended way because it is a bad practice to use defer inside for loop. Alternative is to use `time.After` inside the for loop instead of `time.NewTimer` as we don't have to stop `time.After`. But `time.After` causes resource leak if function exits before the timer fires([Source](https://golang.org/src/time/sleep.go)).

Comment: in this case, you better use context with timeout... because 1) your for is irrelevant, to a new ticker (which starts every single iteration). defer will work on **function exits** , not **scope exits**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use context instead of timer, Where cancel only called when exiting function case condition.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go endProgram(ch)
    printFunc(ch)
}

func printFunc(ch chan string) {
    for {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), getTimeoutDuration())
        select {
        case s := <-ch:
            cancel()
            fmt.Println(s)
            return
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Current value")
        }
    }
}

func endProgram(ch chan string) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 8)
    ch <- "Exit function"
}

func getTimeoutDuration() time.Duration {
    return time.Second * 3
}
```